# How to remove selected symbol from react-select input?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-select

I am using a `react-select` and used `formatOptionLabel` prop to format the options label. Whenever I select any option it is shown in Input and it is also getting that formatted label

I tried passing selectedIcon and removed it on onChange event and that did work, But for that I need to pass it in each option and remove on each onChange.

This is the handleValueChange

```
handleChange = (value) => {
    const { selectedIcon, ...restFields } = value;
    this.setState({
      someKey: restFields
    });
};
```

This is the formatLabel function I have used

```
const formatLabel = (data, restFields) => {
  if (restFields.selectValue[0].value === data.value) {
    return (
      <div>
        {data.selectedIcon}{data.icon}{data.label}
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {data.icon}{data.label}
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Is there a way to format selected value differently when menu is not open. and also I need to apply different styles to both of them.

For example: I want to show ✔️  inside options menu before selected values and when menu is close it should only show the selected value.

Comment: Could you provide some visual design ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For styling you can use the [styling api](https://react-select.com/styles) to style each of the components individually. It provides the initial styles (in docs as `provided`) and the provided props (in docs as `state`) as arguments and returns a styles object.

```
<Select
    { ... }
    styles={{
        option: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            // Your styles here
        }),
        singleValue: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            // Your styles here
        })
    }}
/>
```

If you just want to render a check mark on a selected option you could do it with the styling api and pseudo elements.

```
{
    ...provided,
    '&:before': {
        fontFamily: "FontAwesome" // For example
        content: "\f00c"
    }
}
```

Another method would be to use the [components framework](https://react-select.com/components) to overwrite `Option` and/or `SingleValue` (or `MultiValue`) components (both use the result of `formatOptionLabel`as their immediate React child).

```
const Option = ({ children, ...props }) => <components.Option { ...props }>
    {/* I'll do it my way */}
    { customLabelFormat(props.data) }
    {/* Or like this as per your request */}
    { props.isSelected && <CheckMark /> }
    { children } // To keep default label format as an example
</components.Option>;

<Select
    { ... }
    components={{
        Option
    }}
/>
```

Comment: +1. I did the same adding a custom icon.
Forgot to update here.